# getting "ERROR: AJAX Loading Error: Forbidden" error when trying to upgrade Joomla version 3.5.1 to 3.6.4

Tags: ajax, joomla, version, upgrade

I have tried to upgrade Joomla version from 3.5.1 to 3.6.4 from Joomla control panel by click on "Update Now" button. And got "ERROR: AJAX Loading Error: Forbidden" 
Please see the screenshot http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/1107/5217107686.jpg

How can i fix the issue? Thanks advance for helping !

Comment: https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/11635

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do, make a site backup.

Then manually updated by extracting the update patch package in the root directory.  Go to the link below and find the package that is specifically intended for updating from versions prior to 3.6.X

https://downloads.joomla.org/cms/joomla3/3-6-4

Joomla! 3.6.4 Upgrade Package (.zip)

This package is for performing updates from Joomla! 2.5 and previous 3.x releases to 3.6.4

Please let me know if you have any issues with updating in this manner.

Mike Hamanaka
mike@vertualize.com
707-267-1768

Comment: Yes, Mike Hamanaka is correct!! BUT it is bit tough to beginner. 
Here is the total guide line: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Upgrading_from_Joomla_3.4.x_to_3.5

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED THE PROBLEM !!!
Here is the total solution of my mentioned issue !! I tried hard to solve the issue in various way but failed. 
I fixed my issue once followed this tutorials. 
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Upgrading_from_Joomla_3.4.x_to_3.5

Stay fine with Joomla !!!

Answer (score 0):

"Forbidden" seems to indicate that there is a restriction accessing a file.

Some things to try:

- temporarily revert to the default `.htaccess` file by backing up the current `.htaccess` file and copying `htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess`
- reset file permissions by installing the free or paid version of [Akeeba Admin Tools](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-security/admin-tools) (if it's not already installed) and run the "Fix Permissions" tool
- temporarily disable security extensions or tools that may be restricting access to the update files

In my particular case, it was the last suggestion which was relevant. I worked out how to bypass Sucuri as an administrator by adding an entry in my local hosts file to access
the website via its direct IP address. The update then worked flawlessly.